# Do Azure function slots need the app setting AzureWebJobsStorage?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-deployment-slots

we use Github actions to deploy our function apps, we first deploy it to a slot then swap it.

But I noticed this, should I add the `AzureWebJobsStorage` app setting to Azure Function Slots as well or ignore this warning? If so, is there a way to avoid this warning?
[image: Github workflow run warnings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, it's required.**

It's used for storing configuration (bindings, triggers, etc.) and logs related to the function app.  As the errors states, it is mandatory.

It's not just some magic floating thing, the function app requires its own storage for its own setup and configuration.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobsstorage